# Calculating sum of squares in PHP

Tags: php, math, sum

Write a program that accepts an integer larger than 1 and calculates the sum of the squares from 1 to that integer. For example, if the integer equals 4, the sum of the squares is 30 (1 + 4 + 9 + 16, notice 4 numbers)

Help plz

Comment: HAHA. You can't just say *+500* and think it means anything. No love for you.

Comment: No no it's not, it's just something I want to do :s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$number = intval( $_GET["number"] );
$sum = 0;

for ( $i = 1; $i <= $number; $i++ ) {
    $sum += $i * $i;
}

echo $sum;
```

Here is the html:

```
<form action="mypage.php" method="GET">
   <input type="text" name="number" />
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: looks like you've got 500 rep coming!

Comment: thank u, but how can I make the box thing where I can type the number?